# JQTOUCH with phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, xcode

I have created a app using jqtouch. I have used ajax to send some data to server.
when i'll compile it with phonegap or xcode to Ipad or iphone. will it be able to send data to server ?

I am asking this because i don't know whether ajax will work on cross domain or not in Iphone.

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now i have tested it iphone. Its for everybody who want to create iphone app with jqtouch or javascript jquery and html5.

XHR in iphone does not follow **same origin Policy.**

It means in iphone we can create cross domain ajax request

Note: It works only if you are opening file using **file:///** protocol not using **HTTP** protocol

Answer (score 1):

for that you have to create locally web server environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example to send data to server using AJAX (below).

Place an external hosts in PhoneGap.plist or Cordova.plist.

external hosts

```
  Item : *
```

Just * so you have access to any http sites.

```
#############################

<form class="myformid" method="post" >

//form inputs
<input type="hidden" id="doSubmit" name="doSubmit" value="Submit">

<a href="#" class="submit whiteButton">Submit!</a>
</form>



$('#myformid').submit(function() {

var formdata = $("#myformid").serialize();

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: http://mydomain.com/myphpfile.php,
  data: formdata,
  success: success,
  dataType: json,
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mobile Safari**

iPhone Mobile Safari follows CORS semantic.

Say, your page is hosted on domain `www.example.com`, and the page wishes to loads data from a different domain or sub-domain, say `api.example.com` using ajax.

Then, `api.example.com` must be setup to send the proper CORS header:
[See, CORS topic in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Alternatively, you can also use `JSONP` as a common workaround. The disadvantage of `JSONP` is  that you page will not receive the proper HTTP error code.

**Phonegap**

If you are using it with Phonegap, then you need to add the host name (wildcard are supported) in `ExtenralHosts` attribute array in `Resources/Supporting Files/Cordova.plist`.

**Desktop with local page**

It is usual the case you like to debug on a Desktop browser.

For Desktop, if and only if the page resides locally (i.e., `file:///`), the behavior is browser dependent. By default, Safari (both on Mac and Windows) allows a local page perform ajax to any hosts.

With Chrome, however, it requires CORS header just like the non-local case. The CORS header must include `file:///` as acceptable domain for CORS ajax to work. JSONP also work on Chrome.